# Can't make my next button work to slide in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, i got a kinda hard problem. I've tried my best to solve it, but it seems to be everything alright. I got a slider banner with 3 imgs. I can make then slide properly automatically, but my next/prev button aren't working. Right now i'm working just on the next button, and i can't make it go back to the first image after the slider gets to its end. Look:

This is the html where i keep the images:

```
<div class="eight columns all" id="imdivs">
    <img src="img/slide_1.jpg"  class="img-slide ativa">
    <img src="img/slide_2.jpg"  class="img-slide">
    <img src="img/slide_3.jpg"  class="img-slide">
    <!--<p>>></p> -->
</div>

<!-- The nav buttons -->
<div class="eight columns">
    <img src="img/seta2.png" class="slide-seta" onclick="voltaSlide();">
    <img src="img/seta1.png" class="slide-seta" id="btn-nxt" onclick="avancaSlide();">
</div>
```

The JavaScript that makes it change automatically:

```
    var proximaImagem = 1;//this is the var where i keep the value of the next img
    var zIndexAtual = 0;//this is the initial zIndex value

    function avancarImagem(){
        var imagens = document.getElementById("imdivs").children;//here i get all the html under the div imdivs
        var imagem = imagens[proximaImagem];//and here is the var that kepts the value of the next img
        imagem.style.zIndex = zIndexAtual++;//i add 1 to the zIndex value of the next img
        imagem.style.marginLeft = "0%";//and bring the img to the center

        proximaImagem++;//add 1+ to bring the next img to the var imagem


        if(proximaImagem >= imagens.length){//if i get to the end of the imgs
            proximaImagem = 0;//bring it to the start again
        }


        setTimeout(resetarImagens,2000);//this function reset the value of the imgs
    }

    function resetarImagens(){
       var imagemVisivel = proximaImagem -1;//this var brings the visible img 


        if(imagemVisivel < 0){//if the var is lower than 0(because we make proximaImagem value 0 when it cames to the end)

            imagemVisivel = imagens.length - 1;//the var will be the last img of the slider
        }


        for(var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++){
            if(i != imagemVisivel && i !=proximaImagem){
                imagens[i].style.marginLeft = "-100%";/*
                    decrescent a value of the zIndex and take the img away
                */
                imagens[i].style.zIndex = zIndexAtual--;
            }
            //this is used to bring the imgs back to the right side of the screen, when i need to
            if(proximaImagem == 0 && i != imagemVisivel){
                imagens[0].style.marginLeft = "100%";
                imagens[0].style.zIndex = zIndexAtual--;
            }
            if(proximaImagem == 1 && i != imagemVisivel){
                imagens[1].style.marginLeft = "100%";
                imagens[1].style.zIndex = zIndexAtual--;
            }
            if(proximaImagem == 2 && i != imagemVisivel){
                imagens[2].style.marginLeft = "100%";
                imagens[2].style.zIndex = zIndexAtual--;
            }
        }
    }

var intervalo = setInterval(avancarImagem,4000);//and i make it all every 4s
```

And the next button function, which isn't working:

```
//everything here is more of the same
    var imgsSlide = document.querySelector("#imdivs").children;
    var proxImg = imgsSlide[proximaImagem];//here i take the next img
    var imgAtual = imgsSlide[proximaImagem -1];//and here the img that will fade away

        imgAtual.style.zIndex = zIndexAtual--;
        imgAtual.style.marginLeft = "-100%";

        proxImg.style.zIndex = zIndexAtual++;
        proxImg.style.marginLeft = "0%";

        proximaImagem++;


if(proximaImagem >= imgsSlide.length){//when the value get to the end of the array
    proximaImagem = 1;//make it go back to 1
}

            if(proximaImagem == 1){
                imgAtual = imgsSlide[0];
            }
            console.log("Imagem atual: " + imgAtual);
            console.log("Próxima imagem: " + proximaImagem);
            console.log("Proxima Imagem html: " + proxImg);
            console.log("Div children: " + imgsSlide);
```

But when it get's to the last img of the array, it bring the msg "imgAtual is undefined", and i have no idea why is this happening, since it's basically the same thing as the other function. Can someone help me ? Here is the website with the console.log: www.gabrielozzy.com/site-amor

Comment: From what I see. It looks like there is a possible problem when `proximaImagem` becomes `0`. So in your case `imgsSlide[-1]` isn't valid. In your if-statement change it from `proximaImagem = 0;//make it go back to 0` to `proximaImagem = 1;//make it go back to 1`. See if that works, if it does I'll make this into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your if-statement here:

```
if(proximaImagem >= imgsSlide.length){//when the value get to the end of the array
    proximaImagem = 0;//make it go back to 0
}
```

This means `proximaImagem` could be `0`. So in your code here plugging `0` in:

```
var imgAtual = imgsSlide[proximaImagem -1];
```

Would mean you are doing `0-1` which is `imgsSlide[-1]` an invalid index. Making `imgAtual` undefined. Change the code above so it goes to `1` instead:

```
if(proximaImagem >= imgsSlide.length){//when the value get to the end of the array
    proximaImagem = 1;//make it go back to 1
}
```

*Note*: It seems `proximaImagem` goes from `1..n`. So you also may want to change the condition from `>=` to `>` as well.

Comment: Well i don't get the error anymore ! But it doen't go from the last img to the first one. i tried to fix but i couldn't, and i can't get any error... any tips ? i updated my code now

Comment: @anuseranother Was that working before-hand, is the value of `imgAtual` corrrect?

Comment: No, it wasn't able to bring the first img after the last one. but it though my logical was correct, since imgsSlide[0] = first img.

Comment: Move the part where you are changing `imgAtual.style` to after the if-statement where you do `imgAtual = imgsSlide[0]`. You are changing `imgAtual` to be correct, it just seems like you are doing that *after* you applied the effect in the DOM.

Comment: I think proximaImagem must go to 0, because when i bring it to 1, it just make the third img[2] have the value 1, which is the value of the second img...

Comment: @anuseranother I don't really know the workings of your system by looking at a few of the code snippets, is it possible to provide and example with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or a snippet on the SO site? If you need `proximaImagem` to be `1` then change the values of your variables to be something like: `imgsSlide[proximaImagem];` and `imgAtual = imgsSlide[(proximaImagem+1)%(imgsSlide.length-1)];`

Comment: It didn't solved my problem, but helped me a lot to do imgAtual = imgsSlide[(proximaImagem +1)]%(imgsSlide.length -1), could you please tell me what the % do in this part of the code ?